# if statement for dropdown list item

Tags: html, asp.net, dropdown, listitem

I want to have a delivery address function wherein if i choose a specific city, it will show different choices on the next drop down list item. Here is my html code:

```
<td>
        City
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" placeholder="Income Range...">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="item1" Selected="True">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="item2" Selected="True">--Las Pinas--</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="item3" Selected="True">--Muntinlupa--</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="item4" Selected="True">--Paranaque--</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="item5" Selected="True">--Pasay--</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
```

Like for example i choose item1, it will show different destinations. if item2, it will show another set of destinations and so on. any tricks on this that you might share with me? thank you

i tried having this code behind:

```
if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.Equals("Las Pinas"))
        {
            DropDownListCity2.Items.Add("Almanza");
            DropDownListCity2.Items.Add("Almanza Dos");
        }
```

but it does nothing. please help me out

Comment: by the way the destinations will be shown in dropdown list item as well.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out though.

set autopostback = "true" on the dropdown list.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="item1" Selected="True">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="item2" >Las Pinas</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="item3" >Muntinlupa</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="item4" >Paranaque</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="item5" >Pasay</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>

<td>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListCity2" runat="server" >

                                </asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
```

then put this on the code behind:

```
if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.Equals("Las Pinas"))
        {
            DropDownListCity2.Items.Add("Almanza");
            DropDownListCity2.Items.Add("Almanza Dos");
        }
```